# Error in registering session handler for AWS SDK PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm new to deploying php application on AWS, and I had a problem with $_SESSION, so I tried to implement saving sessions with DynamoDb. However I keep getting this error:

[Mon Nov 18 05:43:57.699008 2019] [php7:error] [pid 3776] [client 122.2.30.250:27863] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Aws\DynamoDb\Session\SessionHandler' not found in /var/app/current/config.php:12\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/app/current/index.php(3): include()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/app/current/config.php on line 12

and this is my code:

```
    <?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;
use Aws\DynamoDb\Session\SessionHandler;

$dynamoDb = DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
    'version' => '2012-08-10',
    'region' => 'ap-southeast-1',
));

$sessionHandler = SessionHandler::factory(array(
    'dynamodb_client' => $dynamoDb,
    'table_name'      => 'sessions',
));
$sessionHandler->register();

session_start();
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, it should be

```
use Aws\DynamoDb\SessionHandler;
```

AWS guide is outdated...